# how to auto increment, if I type 2015 on text1, text2 should display 2016. is there an easy way to this?

Tags: javascript, php, html, jquery, increment

I want this, if I type  2015 on text1, text2 should display 2016
[image]

Comment: Please post your code as text, not images.

Comment: `year2.value = parseInt(s) + 1`?

Comment: What is `text2`? Did you mean `year2`?

Comment: year2.value = parseInt(s) + 1, this is awesome! Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```js
function onkey() {
 var year1 = document.getElementById("year1");
 var s = year1.value;
 var year2 = document.getElementById("year2");
 year2.value = +s + 1;
}
```

Comment: Shouldn't be a `var` on that last line. Also, if the Element is not being detached from the DOM, you should just get it once. This code gets Elements every time onkey fires, which causes unnecessary parser processing.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe you just want to do this:

```js
let doc, html, bod, I; // for use on other loads
addEventListener('load', ()=>{
doc = document; html = doc.documentElement; bod = doc.body; I = id=>doc.getElementById(id);
const year1 = I('year1'), year2 = I('year2');
year1.oninput = function(){
  let v = this.value;
  if(v.match(/^[0-9]+$/)){
    year2.value = +v+1;
  }
  else if(v === ''){
    year2.value = '';
  }
}
}); // end load
```

```html
<input id='year1' type='number' value='' />
<input id='year2' type='number' value='' />
```